# Program with Red-Black Tree falls into infinite loop

Tags: c, algorithm, red-black-tree

I've got a implementation of R-B tree based on the pseudocode in  [this](http://ressources.unisciel.fr/algoprog/s00aaroot/aa00module1/res/%5BCormen-AL2011%5DIntroduction_To_Algorithms-A3.pdf)  book
starting at page 308. I've translated the pseudocode to C to have a working program and to make it easier for me to understand how RB trees work through debugging with but  unfortunately the program falls (sometimes, depending on the input) into infinite loop in this function:

```
void InsFixRBTREE(Tree*& tree, node*& newnode){
    node* temp = newnode;
    node* temp2 = tree->dummy;
    if(tree->root == newnode){
        newnode->color = 'B';
        return;
    }
    while(temp->parent->color == 'R'){
        if(temp->parent == temp->parent->parent->left){
            temp2 = temp->parent->parent->right;
            if(temp2->color == 'R'){
                temp->parent->color = 'B';
                temp2->color = 'B';
                temp->parent->parent->color = 'R';
                temp = temp->parent->parent;
            }
            else if ( temp == temp->parent->right){
                temp = temp->parent;
                RotateLeft(tree, temp);
            }else{
                temp->parent->color = 'B';
                temp->parent->parent->color = 'R';
                RotateRight(tree, temp->parent->parent);
            }
        }else {//if uncle is on the rightside
            temp2 = temp->parent->parent->left;
            if(temp2->color == 'R'){
                temp->parent->color = 'B';
                temp2->color = 'B';
                temp->parent->parent->color = 'R';
                temp = temp->parent->parent;
            }
            else if ( temp == temp->parent->left){
                temp = temp->parent;
                RotateRight(tree, temp);
            }else{
                temp->parent->color = 'B';
                temp->parent->parent->color = 'R';
                RotateLeft(tree, temp->parent->parent);
            }
        }
    }
    tree->root->color = 'B';
}
```

I don't understand RB trees fully enough and help with that problem would greatly help me with learning how they work. The  full RB tree implementation code in my program:

```
struct node{
    node* left;
    node* right;
    node* leftneighbour;
    node* rightneighbour;
    node* parent;
    unsigned int value;
    char color;
};
struct Tree{
    node* root;
    node* dummy;
};


node* ReturnSmallest(Tree* &tree){
    node* temp = tree->root;
    node* behind = tree->dummy;
    while(temp != tree->dummy){
        behind = temp;
        temp = temp->left;
    }
    return behind;

}
node* ReturnBiggest(Tree* &tree){
    node* temp = tree->root;
    node* behind = tree->dummy;
    while(temp != tree->dummy){
        behind = temp;
        temp = temp->right;
    }
    return behind;
}
void RotateRight(Tree*& tree, node* &newnode){
    node* temp = newnode->left;
    newnode->left = temp->right;
    if(temp->right != tree->dummy){
        temp->right->parent = newnode;
    }
    temp->parent = newnode->parent;
    if(newnode->parent == tree->dummy){
        tree->root = temp;
    }else if (newnode == newnode->parent->right){
     newnode->parent->right = temp;
    }else{
        newnode->parent->left = temp;
    }
    temp->right = newnode;
    newnode->parent = temp;

}
void RotateLeft(Tree*& tree, node* &newnode){
   node* temp = newnode->right;
   newnode->right = temp->left;
   if(temp->left != tree->dummy){
       temp->left->parent = newnode;
   }
   temp->parent = newnode->parent;
   if(newnode->parent == tree->dummy){
       tree->root = temp;
   }else if (newnode == newnode->parent->left){
    newnode->parent->left = temp;
   }else{
       newnode->parent->right = temp;
   }
   temp->left = newnode;
   newnode->parent = temp;
}
void DelFixRBTREE(Tree* &tree, node* &newnode){
    node* temp = newnode;
    node* uncletemp = tree->dummy;
    while(temp->color == 'B' && temp != tree->root){
        if(temp == temp->parent->left){
             uncletemp = temp->parent->right;
             if(uncletemp->color == 'R'){
                 uncletemp->color = 'B';
                 temp->parent->color = 'R';
                 RotateLeft(tree, temp->parent);
                 uncletemp = temp->parent->right;
             }
             if(uncletemp->left->color == 'B' && uncletemp->right->color == 'B'){
                 uncletemp->color = 'R';
                 temp = temp->parent;
             }
             else if (uncletemp->right->color == 'B'){
                 uncletemp->left->color = 'B';
                 uncletemp->color = 'R';
                 RotateRight(tree, uncletemp);
                 uncletemp = temp->parent->right;
             }else{
                 uncletemp->color = temp->parent->color;
                 temp->parent->color = 'B';
                 uncletemp->right->color = 'B';
                 RotateLeft(tree, temp->parent);
                 temp = tree->root;
             }
        }else{
            if(temp == temp->parent->right){
                 uncletemp = temp->parent->left;
                 if(uncletemp->color == 'R'){
                     uncletemp->color = 'B';
                     temp->parent->color = 'R';
                     RotateRight(tree, temp->parent);
                     uncletemp = temp->parent->left;
                 }
                 if(uncletemp->right->color == 'B' && uncletemp->left->color == 'B'){
                     uncletemp->color = 'R';
                     temp = temp->parent;
                 }
                 else if (uncletemp->left->color == 'B'){
                     uncletemp->right->color = 'B';
                     uncletemp->color = 'R';
                     RotateLeft(tree, uncletemp);
                     uncletemp = temp->parent->left;
                 }else{
                     uncletemp->color = temp->parent->color;
                     temp->parent->color = 'B';
                     uncletemp->left->color = 'B';
                     RotateRight(tree, temp->parent);
                     temp = tree->root;
                 }
        }
    }
}
}
void InsFixRBTREE(Tree*& tree, node*& newnode){
    node* temp = newnode;
    node* temp2 = tree->dummy;
    if(tree->root == newnode){
        newnode->color = 'B';
        return;
    }
    while(temp->parent->color == 'R'){
        if(temp->parent == temp->parent->parent->left){
            temp2 = temp->parent->parent->right;
            if(temp2->color == 'R'){
                temp->parent->color = 'B';
                temp2->color = 'B';
                temp->parent->parent->color = 'R';
                temp = temp->parent->parent;
            }
            else if ( temp == temp->parent->right){
                temp = temp->parent;
                RotateLeft(tree, temp);
            }else{
                temp->parent->color = 'B';
                temp->parent->parent->color = 'R';
                RotateRight(tree, temp->parent->parent);
            }
        }else {//if uncle is on the rightside
            temp2 = temp->parent->parent->left;
            if(temp2->color == 'R'){
                temp->parent->color = 'B';
                temp2->color = 'B';
                temp->parent->parent->color = 'R';
                temp = temp->parent->parent;
            }
            else if ( temp == temp->parent->left){
                temp = temp->parent;
                RotateRight(tree, temp);
            }else{
                temp->parent->color = 'B';
                temp->parent->parent->color = 'R';
                RotateLeft(tree, temp->parent->parent);
            }
        }
    }
    tree->root->color = 'B';
}
void RBAddToTree(Tree* &tree, node* newnode){
    node* temp = tree->root;
    node* behind = tree->dummy;
    (newnode)->left = tree->dummy;
    (newnode)->right = tree->dummy;
    newnode->color = 'R';
    (newnode)->leftneighbour = tree->dummy;
    (newnode)->rightneighbour = tree->dummy;
    (newnode)->parent = tree->dummy;
    if((tree->root) == tree->dummy){
        (tree->root) = newnode;
        newnode->color = 'B';
        return;
    }
    do{
        if(temp == tree->dummy){
            (newnode)->parent = behind;
            if(behind->value < (newnode)->value){
                behind->right = newnode;
            }else{
               behind->left = newnode;
            }
            break;
        }else{
            behind = temp;
            if((newnode)->value > temp->value)
                temp = temp->right;
            else if ((newnode)->value < temp->value)
                temp  = temp->left;
            else{
                temp->rightneighbour = (newnode);
                (newnode)->leftneighbour = temp;
                return;
            }
        }
    }while(1);
    InsFixRBTREE(tree, newnode);
}
void DeleteSmallest(node*& smallest, Tree*& tree){
    node* temp = smallest;
    if(smallest == tree->root){
        if(smallest->rightneighbour != tree->dummy){
            tree->root = smallest->rightneighbour;
            smallest->rightneighbour->leftneighbour = tree->dummy;
            smallest->rightneighbour->color = smallest->color;
            smallest->rightneighbour->right = smallest->right;
            if(smallest->right != tree->dummy){
                smallest->right->parent = smallest->rightneighbour;
            }
            smallest->right = tree->dummy;
            smallest->rightneighbour = tree->dummy;
        }else{//kiedy nie ma
            tree->root = smallest->right;
            if(smallest->right != tree->dummy){
                smallest->right->parent = tree->dummy;
             }
             smallest->right = tree->dummy;
              if(temp->color == 'B')
              DelFixRBTREE(tree, tree->root);
        }

    }else if (smallest->rightneighbour != tree->dummy){
        smallest->parent->left = smallest->rightneighbour;
        smallest->rightneighbour->parent = smallest->parent;
        if(smallest->right != tree->dummy){
            smallest->right->parent = smallest->rightneighbour;
        }
        smallest->rightneighbour->right = smallest->right;
        smallest->rightneighbour->leftneighbour = tree->dummy;
        smallest->rightneighbour->color = smallest->color;
        smallest->rightneighbour = tree->dummy;
        smallest->parent = tree->dummy;
        smallest->right = tree->dummy;
    }else if(smallest->right != tree->dummy){
        char color = temp->color;
        temp = smallest->right;
        smallest->right->parent = smallest->parent;
        smallest->parent->left = smallest->right;
        smallest->parent = tree->dummy;
        smallest->right = tree->dummy;
        if(color == 'B')
        DelFixRBTREE(tree, temp);
    }else{//kiedy jest leaf
        smallest->parent->left = tree->dummy;
        smallest->parent = tree->dummy;
         if(temp->color == 'B')
        DelFixRBTREE(tree, smallest->right);
    }

}
void DeleteBiggest(node*& biggest, Tree*& tree){
    node* temp = biggest;
    if(biggest == tree->root){
        if(biggest->rightneighbour != tree->dummy){
            tree->root = biggest->rightneighbour;
            biggest->rightneighbour->leftneighbour = tree->dummy;
            biggest->rightneighbour->color = biggest->color;
            biggest->rightneighbour->left = biggest->left;
            if(biggest->left != tree->dummy){
                biggest->left->parent = biggest->rightneighbour;
            }
            biggest->left = tree->dummy;
            biggest->rightneighbour = tree->dummy;
        }else{
            tree->root = biggest->left;
            if(biggest->left != tree->dummy){
                biggest->left->parent = tree->dummy;
             }
             biggest->left = tree->dummy;
             if(temp->color == 'B')
             DelFixRBTREE(tree, tree->root);
        }

    }else if (biggest->rightneighbour != tree->dummy){
        biggest->parent->right = biggest->rightneighbour;
        biggest->rightneighbour->parent = biggest->parent;
        if(biggest->left != tree->dummy){
            biggest->left->parent = biggest->rightneighbour;
        }
        biggest->rightneighbour->left = biggest->left;
        biggest->rightneighbour->leftneighbour = tree->dummy;
        biggest->rightneighbour->color = biggest->color;
        biggest->rightneighbour = tree->dummy;
        biggest->parent = tree->dummy;
        biggest->left = tree->dummy;
    }else if(biggest->left != tree->dummy){
        char color = temp->color;
        temp = biggest->left;
        biggest->left->parent = biggest->parent;
        biggest->parent->right = biggest->left;
        biggest->parent = tree->dummy;
        biggest->left = tree->dummy;
        if(color == 'B')
        DelFixRBTREE(tree, temp);
    }else{
        biggest->parent->right = tree->dummy;
        biggest->parent = tree->dummy;
        if(temp->color == 'B')
        DelFixRBTREE(tree, biggest->left);
    }

}
```

As I said the implementation is 1:1 pseudocode translation to C from the book.
The rest of the program worked well with unbalanced BST so I don't think it is the problem. The rest of the program only needs to change smallest/biggest number from this tree so that's why there's no implementation for deleting nodes with two children etc. I'm sorry if this question violates any rules but I really can't understand why it doesn't work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That code isn't C, it's probably C++.

Comment: As for your problem, scale back your ambitions a little and try to do it one step at a time. After each little step, you stop and test and fix the problems you have. I also recommend you [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), and try to simplify things in general as well as compartmentalize and split some code that could be shared into separate functions. Maybe even put non-common code into functions as well to make it easier to follow along what's happening.

Comment: That's a lot of code to sort through with no idea of where the problem is. You need to put some debug output statements in there so you can get an idea of where it's going off the rails. And then some time with your debugger once you've traced the problem to a smaller bit of code. If you don't know how to use your debugger, now is a perfect time to learn.

Comment: I'd re-tag this `c++`, but I'm a bit baffled because OP seems to be convinced he's writing in C when it's definitely C++.

Comment: To support Somes comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/21/find-a-simpler-problem/